# Como utilizar o PyOpenGL no pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyopengl

Fiz as instalações corretas do PyOpenGL e do Acellerate. Consigo usar as bibliotecas tranquilamente na IDLE do python 3.7.2, entretanto quando vou tentar fazer um import delas usando a IDE Pycharm não consigo utilizar as bibliotecas. Oque devo fazer? Provavelmente devo copiar alguma pasta para algum diretorio do Pycharm, mas não sei em qual ;/

Answer (score 2):

Verifique suas **configurações de execução e depuração**: [run/debug configurations (em inglês)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Veja se o **caminho para o interpretador** (*Python interpreter*), é o mesmo onde você instalou os pacotes ou usa em outra ferramenta.